# (SSG-WSG) The skills frame work in the API is not tally with the skills framework shown in the website

Tags: api, ssg

The skills framework in the API is not tally with the skills framework shown in the website. For example, the API
https://public-api.ssg-wsg.sg/skillsFramework/sectors
shows only 29 sectors, but there are 34 sectors in the website
https://www.skillsfuture.gov.sg/skills-framework

Would the API be synchronized with the data in the website?

Answer (score 0):

They don't look like they contain the same information, maybe you can check with Skillsfuture?
https://www.myskillsfuture.gov.sg/content/portal/en/header/faqs/for-further-assistance.html